# Remove previous letter if '/' Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple program where it removes the previous letter when there exists a `"/"` after the character. Also, if there are two `"//"` after two characters, it should remove the last two characters. The number of `/` only exists if there a similar number of characters before so `//` in this scenario: `aa//`.

for example

```
x = 'abc/c/dd//a'
print x.rstrip('/')
```

it should return

```
aba
```

another example

```
x = '/aab//'
print x.rstrip('/')
```

should return

```
a
```

I have seen solutions trying the method above, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Is there an optimal solution for this?

Comment: What if there are three "/" in a row? What if the string starts with "/" so there's nothing previous to remove?

Comment: You say `"//" before two characters`, but that's not the case in your example, where "//" is before only *one* character.

Comment: What is the expected result for `'a/bb/ccc////'`?

Comment: What's the idea behind `x.rstrip('/')`?

Comment: @Cipher, you write *The number of / only exists if there a similar number of characters before* -- Does this mean that you assert that the number of `/`characters is less or equal to the numbers of normal characters?

Comment: `x.rstrip('/')` -- this returns a new string and keeps `x` unchanged; it returns a copy of `x` with any `/` characters on the right end removed, so `assert '/a///'.rstrip('/') == '/a'`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function can do this :

```py
def stripStr(x, special_char="/"):
    buff = ""
    for char in x:
        if char == special_char:
            buff = buff[:-1]
        else:
            buff += char
    return buff

assert stripStr('abc/c/dd//a') == 'aba'
assert stripStr('abc////cde/dd///a') == 'ca'
```

The idea is to reconstruct the string (in the `buff` variable) character after character. You simply need to keep appending each char except when you find a `/` then you have to remove the last char of the string.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Is the result of `'a/bb/ccc////'`  by design?